# How I can make this piece of website responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, css-grid

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(680px, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header header header header header header";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/536/thumb-1920-53625.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.15);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.Facebook,
.Youtube {
  max-width: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.Facebook:hover,
.Youtube:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#social {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul>li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#button {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

#button>h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

#button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

  <header>
    <nav>

      <div id="social">
        <a href="https://www.Facebook.com"><img class="Facebook" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-square-8/64/social_media-09-512.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://www.Youtube.com"><img class="Youtube" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-square-8/64/social_media-49-512.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>

      <div id="button">
        <h4>MAKE A RESERVATION</h4>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

</div>
```

I tried flex-wrap on all flex parents' children, it didn't work like I wanted, some items collapsed. I tried to set max or min-width to 100% or something like that to nav. It didn't work. I set flex to 1 1 auto but the button became very wide and it basically didn't work well even when I set 0 1 auto.

I tried to set the grid system to 12 columns(I still apply that as you see) and again, that didn't work a bit.

How I could make it responsive?

Comment: Your problem probably lies in your minmax/repeat functions?

Comment: @vicgoyso I don't understand. What's wrong with them? I mean repeat function is for repeating 12 column with 1 fr for each one so I think it's fine and minmax is to decide the height of every row and making it changable for every item. Please explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your code like this:

*Comments added inside the code*

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(680px, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header header header header header header";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/536/thumb-1920-53625.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.15);
  /*justify-content: space-between; removed*/
  justify-content: center; /*added*/
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*added*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/*added*/
ul {
  padding:0;
}
/*****/

ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.Facebook,
.Youtube {
  max-width: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.Facebook:hover,
.Youtube:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#social {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul>li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; useless*/
}

#button {
  /*justify-self: center;
  align-self: center; removed*/
  margin:auto; /*added*/
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /*position: relative;
  left: 100px; removed*/
}

#button>h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

#button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div id="social">
        <a href="https://www.Facebook.com"><img class="Facebook" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-square-8/64/social_media-09-512.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://www.Youtube.com"><img class="Youtube" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-square-8/64/social_media-49-512.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      
      <div id="button">
        <h4>MAKE A RESERVATION</h4>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I changed justify-content to space-between because it's the way I wanted it. It still has some problems as the items are not positioned well but I think I will just override that by Media Queries to make it better. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Boypro no you don't need space-between because I used margin:auto with the middle element and it's exactly the same ;) .. and the use of center i useful for small device where you can see that the element get centre instead of being left aligned

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS `media tag` to make responsive design & you can adjust your design as per your width:-

**For Mobile View:-**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
/* your css will be here and this code will be working just in mobile device */
}
```

**For iPad View:-**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
/* your css will be here and this code will be working just in iPad device */
}
```